# Is this the right way to use open() in python? its showing an error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using the code below:

```
txt = open("/data/cards/deckofcards.txt").read().splitlines()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/cards/deckofcards.txt'
```

Comment: The error is _very_ clear. What have you tried?

Comment: Try running this shell command: `ls /data/cards/deckofcards.txt`. That should show you that the file does not exist in the path shown. Perhaps the file location is _relative_ to the current directory, in which case remove the leading `/`.

Comment: what is meant by Traceback(most recent call last)?

Comment: LMGTFY: https://anenadic.github.io/2014-11-10-manchester/novice/python/07-errors.html

Comment: I have a folder named DATA in my home directory (/home/data),I wanted to display the deckofcards.txt file from the cards folder which is in data folder (/home/data/cards/deckofcards.txt/) on the terminal by using python.i tried the code above i am facing an error.

Comment: `/home/data` is your username `data` ?

Comment: No no my pwd is home /vamsi /  and I meant to say the folder data is in home

Answer (score 0):

txt=open("/home/vamsi/data/cards/deckofcards.txt").read().splitlines()
print(v)

I missed the (/home/vamsi) path.I misunderstood that pwd is by default and no need to give it in open().I figured it out and it is working fine.in open() we should also give pwd also to open the (.txt,.tsv etc..)file as we needed.

thank you,
[screen shot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CossG.png)

Answer (score -1):

Give the absolute path of the file.
It would be something like C:/Desktop/data/card.txt.
The directory you mentioned does not exist and hence it is giving you that error.

Comment: You have no reason to assume this is a Windows machine, nor that the path is relative (it could be absolute, but non-existent).